# Pass variable cart total to PayPal for Subscription (using Enhanced Recurring Payments w. Website Payments Standard)

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

**Summary: Trying to pass along a *variable* Monthly Subscription cost to PayPal based on user-selected options on a form I created. Working within Website Payments Standard with Enhanced Recurring Payment option, is this possible?**

**Details**:
User visits "shop" page, which is a form with 4 line items, each line item consisting of 2-7 options, each option with an associated price.

For example, line item 1 is "size of business" with the options being:
a) 1-3 employees - $10
b) 4+ employees - $12.50

User goes through the list and chooses 1 option for each line item and some javascript calculates the total due on the fly.

Is it possible to pass this total to PayPal, not as a one-time cost, rather as the base cost for a monthly subscription?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just change the value you're passing for `a3`, rather than `amount`.

Is there a problem you're running into?